# Satisfying the 'Contribution to the Profession' requirement of the GISP-AP Certification, does GIS SE make the cut?

Tags: australia, career, new-zealand, certification

Does participation in moderated online communities such as GIS SE count towards satisfying the '**Contribution to the Profession**' requirement of the [GISP-AP Certification](http://www.sssi.org.au/userfiles/docs/Spatial%20Information%20&%20Cartography/documents_1362548437618368491.pdf) issued by the Survey and Spatial Sciences Institute (AU/NZ)?

If participation does count, how is it translated into a **point score** using the **Contributions Point Schedule** (pages 31 to 38 of [this](http://www.sssi.org.au/userfiles/docs/Spatial%20Information%20&%20Cartography/documents_1362548437618368491.pdf) document)?

I have emailed this question to SSSI. No response as yet.
I've also seen a similar question and response [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170434/what-can-help-gain-contribution-points-for-gisp-certificate) about the GISCI Certification program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from the Chairman of the GISP-AP Certification Panel:

"For contributions to a moderated online geospatial community, I recommend you claim under 8.2 "Volunteer Work".

You will also need to provide proof of your contribution, perhaps a letter from the moderator of the online community?"

**Under section 8.2 - Volunteer Work, a contributor earns 0.05 points per every hour of volunteer work**

Answer (score 2):

I think the response you receive from Survey and Spatial Sciences Institute (AU/NZ) will be the most sound answer you most likely will receive. Saying that if it is accepted in some for or another, I think like the link you provided about the GISCI Certification Program that provide their response, will still be something that needs to be considered on GIS SE.

> Here is the most recent response from Bill Hodge, Director of GISCI.
>   "...that is an excellent question, and I do consider that to be a worthy activity. The problem is whether or not the forums have some way to track and rate activity. If they do have some ability to show activity, then this would certainly count!"